# Center button tag on top of bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Pretty cut and dry question... Not big on HTML but trying to get the button, like in the example below, center on top of the bootstrap carousel. Sadly I got to use the button tag.

http://www.codeply.com/go/RY7yBxnnNj

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: please add the code you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.centerbutton {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-23px;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Please note:

- adjust margin-top to half the button's height
- adjust margin-left to half the button's width
- it will position to the first relative parent

Comment: Thanks for that. Very much appropriate it